# How does the unit testing works in Web API testing

Tags: .net, unit-testing, .net-core, asp.net-web-api, xunit

I have a below code which is working fine. But I am not able to understand how **act** part works in below code. When I am debugging the code, it's not hitting to DB which is expected in unit testing as we do it using mock data instead of actual DB data. But then what is the use of below line and how does it make test successful while comparing the result with mock data.

```
[Fact]
        public async Task GetEmployee_ShouldReturnOk()

        {

            //arrange
            var employees = fixure.Create<List<Employee>>();
            var empName = fixure.Create<string>();

            empService.Setup(x => x.GetEmployee(empName)).ReturnsAsync(employees);
            
            //act
            //this line is calling a controller method but not hitting to data access layer. So from where its getting data?
            var employeesResult = await EmpController.GetEmployee(empName);
            //assert
            employeesResult.Should().NotBeNull();
            employeesResult.Should().BeAssignableTo<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Employee>>>();
            employeesResult.Result.Should().BeAssignableTo<OkObjectResult>();
            empService.Verify(x=>x.GetEmployee(empName), Times.Once());
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

The first thing to state is that you're not "really" api testing here. You're just doing a unit test of a controller. I presume its "getting its data from the mock you're setting up with the "empService" although that is just an educated guess based on your mock and that we can't see the controller code.

If you want to do actual API testing, then I'd recommend looking into the WebApplicationFactory.

Good luck!